# Accessing an element in identity matrix

Tags: opencv

I want to make an Identity matrix and then subtract some different floats from its diagonal elements. Here is what I have done:

```
cv::Mat R = cv::Mat::eye(trainingMat.rows,trainingMat.rows, CV_32F);
```

(`trainingMat` is an other matrix)And here is the strange thing. When I write:

```
std::cerr<<R.at<double>(0,0)<<std::endl;
```

I get an strange number(but it should be 1.0f right?). And when I do this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < trainingMat.rows; i++){
            std::cerr<<R.at<double>(i,i)<<std::endl;
        }
```

again I get some strange numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130162/how-to-access-pixel-values-of-cv-32f-cv-64f-mat Try `R.at<float>(0,0)`

Comment: Or define your Mat of type `CV_64F`

Comment: "but it should be 1.0f" -- You explicitly cast to `double`, why do you expect to get a `float` (different type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met this kind of situation several times which turn out to be the problem of Wrong Type of the Mat. 
Here are some pairs that you may keep in mind.

```
CV_8U <-> uchar
CV_32S <-> int
CV_32F <-> float
CV_64F <-> double
```

TYPE float takes up 4 bytes, and double takes up 8 bytes in the memory.
You try to using **double** to take **one** element, but **in fact**, you take **two** elements, and use these two to represent one. so you got the unexpected number.