# Printing CV_32F opencv matrix values

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vector

I want to print the values of `1x3` vector of ones `CV_32F` elements:

```
cv::Mat O = cv::Mat::ones(1, 3, CV_32F);
for(int i=0;i<O.cols;i++)
    std::cout<<O.at<float>(1,i)<<" ";
std::cout<<std::endl;
std::cout<<O<<std::endl;
```

However the code above prints:

```
1.4013e-43 1.12104e-43 0 //WHAT?
[1, 1, 1]  //correct
```

Why this happens? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130162/how-to-access-pixel-values-of-cv-32f-cv-64f-mat) question but didn't help.

Comment: Not familiar with openCV but gonna take a stab: should it be std::cout<<O.at<float>(0,i).....?

Comment: ...ops...This is embarrassing

Comment: Post it as an answer and I'll chose it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, the loop needs to start at 0!

```
std::cout<<O.at<float>(0,i)<<" ";
```